# Jackson conditional deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'd like to deserialize JSON into pojos in different ways, depending on the incoming json. For example, the incoming JSON could come in one of two forms:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "name": "a name",
        "another": "value"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "foo": "a name"
}
```

The receiver pojos:

```
class Container {
    Foo foo;
}

class Foo {
    String name;
    String another;
}
```

The first case is easy, the default behavior handles it. In the second case, though, I'd like to have the system create a Foo and then assign the incoming string to the "name" field.

I could not figure out how to do this using Jackson's support for polymorphic deserialization. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `JsonDeserializer<Container>`.

In it you can check to see if the field "foo" is an `ObjectNode` or a `TextNode` and choose how you want to deserialize the object based on that.